# Class Aty\TestTask\Controller\Router does not exist

Tags: magento2

I was trying to add custom routes. 
There is my di.xml:
(app/code/Aty/TestTask/etc/frontend/di.xml)

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="testTask" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Aty\TestTask\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

there is my controller: 
(app/code/Aty/TestTask/Controller/Router.php)

```
<?
namespace Aty\TestTask\Controller;

class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    protected $actionFactory;
    protected $_response;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response
    )
    {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
        $this->_response = $response;
    }

    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        Logic is here             
    }
}
```

And there is my route.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="testTask" frontName="testTask">
            <module name="Aty_TestTask" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

But when I open any page I see

> Class Aty\TestTask\Controller\Router does not exist.

Where is my fault?

Comment: route.xml should be routes.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Go to :app/code/Aty/TestTask/etc/frontend/di.xml

Please replace this

```
 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
```

This

```
 <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">60</item>
```

Clear cache and recompile.

Comment: why it must be 60?

Answer (score 0):

You may have the wrong file name `route.xml` should be `routes.xml` and that `di.xml` should be in the frontend at `Aty/TestTask/etc/frontend/` and same for `routes.xml`